# NameError: name 'asyncio' is not defined; In running discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm working on a small discord bot for a server I made, however I've run into a problem. Whenever I try to run the bot (using `python3.4 lilac.py`), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lilac.py", line 7, in <module>
    @asyncio.coroutine
NameError: name 'asyncio' is not defined
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0xb61ad470>
```

I tried to install it via `python3.4 -m pip install asyncio`, and even though it said the install was successful, I still get the error. This is the full code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&&', description="Description     here")

@bot.event
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
```

Is there anything I didn't install correctly? Am I calling asyncio incorrectly? Any help is appreciated, I can give more info if needed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a reasonable reason to down-vote this question (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/75103). It contains a concise problem description, a small self-contained code sample that reproduces the error, a full traceback, and is sensibly tagged. IOW, it's close to the gold standard for how a question should be presented.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to import `asyncio` in your code.
just add the following into the first line of your code

```
import asyncio
```

Comment: Lord, I'm an idiot. I've been working on stuff for the past 12 hours and I guess I was just in a rush to get this done. Thank you for responding (I'll mark this as accepted once 5 minutes is up, since it won't let me atm)!

Comment: Welcome. happy to help

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `import asyncio` - add the import before you're using it and it should work.